# How could I forcibly remount a device without a reboot?

Tags: mount, boot, devices

How could I forcibly remount a device? Say I have a device (`/dev/shm`) which from some reason isn't mounted, how could I remount it without rebooting the system? In other words, I need a remount without reboot.

Please share a way and give your opinion on the best practices you know for using it.

Comment: Does the normal `mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev tmpfs /dev/shm` work?

Comment: As I'm new to Linux, I think I was wrong in my analysis and the device was mounted, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put `-o` option to `remount` for changing flags.

`mount -t tmpfs -o remount,rw,nosuid,nodev tmpfs /dev/shm`

For details read about "FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS" section.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mount.8.html